# how to add a group in a exist QSettings file

Tags: qt, qsettings

I have already created a `QSettings` file in my code, but a new function need to add a new group in my `QSettings` file, so I still use the code:

```
settings = QSettings()
settings.beginGroup("showItem")
settings.setValue("show", True)
settings.endGroup()
```

but the noting has to do with my old `QSettings` file! So, somebody know how to add a new group in `QSettings` file?

Comment: Did you forget to set the file?

Comment: You know that depending on the OS you're running, the QSetting file is written at the end of the program execution ?

Comment: What is `True`? Is it typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `setValue` in the function where I close the application, and then restore the value on its next run. For example,

```
void MyApp::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* e) 
{
    (void)(e);  // UNUSED PARAMETER

    QSettings settings("MpApp", abc);
    settings.setValue("show", x); // Where x is a bool datatype 
}
```

and use this code while initializing to restore the value:

```
QSettings settings("MyApp", abc);
bool x = settings.value("show").toBool();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: There is `Q_UNUSED` macro in Qt. And you suggested a workaround, but not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no event loop running, then you may call `QSettings::sync` directly to force applying of changes.